# How do I run jQuery form validation by class?

Tags: jquery, validation, css

I've been using the jQuery form validator, but I can't seem to figure out how to trigger it by class. Take this example:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      date: true
    }
  }
});
```

Where `field` it is expecting the name of the particular input. But, what if I have the following:

```
<input class="date".... />
```

How can I tell the validator to validate all inputs with a "date" class as a date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
    date: {
        required: true,
        date: true,
    },
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Just supplying the input with a class that matches one of the validation methods is sufficient to have the plugin validate that input using the method.  If this isn't working for you, then I'd use Firefox/Firebug to check to make sure that you don't have some javascript errors that are causing the plugin not to run.